# Splicing a number in javascript

Tags: javascript, slice

I am trying to write 1k 10k and 100k and I am trying to find a form of .splice but for numbers that way I can turn 1000, 10000, and 100000 to k's while using the same formula for each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just divide by 1000.

```js
[1000, 10000, 100000].forEach(x => console.log(x / 1000 + 'k'));
```

To display one decimal place when needed:

```js
[1320, 14302, 193234].forEach(x => console.log(+(x / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'k'))
```

Comment: Now this answer does work but I want to also be able to show the first decimal place such as 1320 will show 1.3k and 14.302 will show 14.3k and 193234 will show 193.2k, Is there a way to do this using the same formula?

Comment: `[1320, 193234].forEach(x => console.log(+(x / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'k'))`

Comment: @HelpMeWithJavascript Glad to help.

Comment: Thanks I accepted it! I just had to wait a bit before it let me accept it since this question was basically just posted! :D

Answer (score 0):

```js
function kFormatter(num) {
  return Math.abs(num) >= 1000 ? Math.sign(num) * ((Math.abs(num) / 1000).toFixed(1)) + 'k' : Math.sign(num) * Math.abs(num)
}

console.log(kFormatter(1200)); // 1.2k
console.log(kFormatter(-1200)); // -1.2k
console.log(kFormatter(999.9)); // 999.9
console.log(kFormatter(-900)); // -900
```

Comment: Try putting in `999.1`, will give the wrong result

Comment: sorry, my mistake I updated the answer 
it should be num >= 1000

Comment: `Math.sign(num) * Math.abs(num)` is just `num` what are you doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to get all the characters from the start to the string's length minus 3, then concatenate a period and the character in the second last position:

```js
function format(s) {
  s = String(s)
  return s.substring(0, s.length - 3) + "." + s.substring(s.length - 3, s.length - 2) + 'k';
}
console.log(format(1000))
console.log(format(1100))
console.log(format(10000))
console.log(format(11000))
```

If the number is smaller than 1000, we can perform a length check that prepends `0` to the result if the length of the string is less than 4:

```js
function format(s) {
  s = String(s)
  return (s.length < 4 ? '0' : s.substring(0, s.length - 3)) + "." + s.substring(s.length - 3, s.length - 2) + 'k';
}
console.log(format(100))
console.log(format(1000))
console.log(format(1100))
console.log(format(10000))
console.log(format(11000))
```

Comment: might be better user experience to transform to string inside the function instead of expecting a string, also doesnt work if you give it 10 for example

Comment: Also doesnt seem to work quite right for decimal numbers, makes them a factor 100 bigger with 1 decimal place, even better result the more decimals you add :)